# iOS: How to launch call applications like native phone app, skype, lin phone etc from my application

Tags: ios, tel

I have explored `tel://` pattern to establish a call. But in my iPad mini I have only wi-fi support. so this uri fails. What I want to know is if there is nay way write a code such that my application will ask user to choose among all calling feature supporting application.

I tried `callto:` pattern but no luck. any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

To make calls via **Skype** you can use this URL scheme, source is [skype docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745885%28v=office.15%29.aspx#How)

```
BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
if(installed)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];
}
```

To make calls via **facetime** you can use use similar url scheme

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://+123456789"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Hope this helps , There is no such feature which i am aware of that will give you list of all calling apps , but you can manually show an selection option and let user select any of above

Comment: I wish if there can be a standard uri to establish call in iOS to handle all calling feature supporting application

Comment: Unfortunately , there isn't any way in iOS for achieving that. Only option is to do manually.